# Passing JSON to .NET API

Tags: c#, .net, json, routes

I am trying to pass create a [HttpPost] method in .NET that inserts a new row in the database with data sent via JSON.
I am using Postman to test the API but I keep running into the same issue:

```
"Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:13489/api/RegisterController/CreateUser/'.",
"MessageDetail": "No type was found that matches the controller named 'RegisterController'."
```

However, when I am trying to pass just a string, instead of a User object or string with Json format, it works just fine. I guess I am not passing the right object type? 
The route config is as follows

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "DefaultApi",
  routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
  );
```

And here is the post method:

```
    [Route("api/RegisterController/CreateUser/{json}")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage CreateUser( User json)
    {
           // JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);

        string sql = "INSERT INTO user(Email, Password, Name, DateOfBirth, profile_pic) VALUES('" + json.Email + "','" +
                    json.Password + "','" +json.Name + "','"+json.DateOfBirth+"','randomurl');";

        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql, _db.Connection);
        try
        {
            _db.Connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, "User registerd");

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(exception.Message);
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, exception.Message);
        }
        finally { _db.Connection.Close(); }

    }
```

**UPDATE:**
Removed the {json} from the path and now it goes through. However, the User object that I am getting is null. What am I missing again?

**UserModel**

```
public class User
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string ProfilePic { get; set; }
}
```

Code : [image: Code snapshot]

Json: [image: Json Data]

Comment: You do not need to have {json} in your route path since you are using HttpPost. Use just  [Route("api/RegisterController/CreateUser")]

Comment: Another note, if this is every accessible by anyone other than you, it is very prone to SQL Injection. You're allowing a user to directly write queries against your database.

Comment: @KiranBeladiya that makes sense.. Wish I realized that sooner. However, is it right to get a User object or not? I've been googling a bit but this is what I found.

Comment: @xiience Yes, thank you. This is just a dummy project to get started. I am just interested in connecting the back end to the front end

Comment: @MonicaS yes it is right to get User object. If you are posting proper User JSON, this should work.

Comment: @KiranBeladiya I am using postman and it seems that I am but the object is still NULL.

Comment: What does your user model look like? Does the JSON you're posting match?

Comment: @tattarrattat Just updated the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Headers are used to describe the request, not for actual request data.

Send a JSON payload in the body, not by using headers.

So set the header `Content-Type` to `application/json`, and post a JSON body:

```
{
    "Email" : "email",
    "..." : "..."
}
```